# IList<T>.AsReadOnly extension method Not working for Reference type Collection

Tags: c#, readonly

Here is the sample code:
Readonly extension not working for reference type collection. if I would change the Employee to string then it will work.
Could somebody explain why I am getting this behaviour.

```
        List<Employee> Emps = new List<Employee>(2)
        {
            new Employee(){EmpName="E1",Year=2012,EmpID=1},
            new Employee(){EmpName="E2",Year=2012,EmpID=2}
        };
        Emps.ForEach(emp => Debug.WriteLine(emp.EmpName));
        **IList<Employee> readonlyEmp = Emps.AsReadOnly();
        readonlyEmp[0].EmpName = "EMPUpdated";**
        foreach (var emp in readonlyEmp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(emp.EmpName);
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

A `ReadOnlyCollection` prevents modifications of the references in the collection. It does not prevent modifications to the referred objects. If you have a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>`, you cannot change anything, because `string` is immutable. Your `Employee` class is mutable and can be changed.

So the obvious solution would be to make `Employee` immutable. Make the properties readonly and initialize them in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks.Got it.so asreadonly() extension method only prevent the COUNT if object is mutable.

Comment: @mahalingam a readonly collection cannot have items added, removed or **swapped**; for example, with a mutable collection you could do `list[24] = anotherValue;` - you can't do that with a readonly collection. So it isn't just the count.

Comment: Not only the number of elements, but also the references to single elements: You cannot do `readonlyEmp[0] = new Employee();`, even though it would not change `Count`.